# How to pass execution_date as parameter in SparkKubernetesOperator operator?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, airflow

I am trying to find a way to pass the execution_Date to the SparkKubernetesOperator.
Any way its possible to pass that since I will be using execution date for the spark run and s3 partitions.

```
submit_compaction_to_spark = SparkKubernetesOperator(
        task_id="submit_compaction_to_spark",
        application_file="/k8s/compaction_s3.yml",
        namespace=kubernetes_namespace,
        kubernetes_conn_id="kubernetes",
        params={
            "warehouse_path": s3_path,
            "snapshot_expire_time": execution_date,
            "partition_filter": execution_date,
            "k8s_namespace": kubernetes_namespace,
            "docker_image_tag": docker_image_tag,
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `params` only exposes custom values to jinja but it does not render jinja templates inside them.

For example, let's look at this PythonOperator.

```py
op = PythonOperator(
    task_id="my_operator",
    python_callable=lambda **context: print(context['params']),
    params={
        "date": "{{ execution_date }}"
    },
    dag=dag
)
```

The value for the date key is the literal string `"{{ execution_date }}"` and not the rendered value.

```
[2021-03-05 01:24:26,770] {logging_mixin.py:103} INFO - {'date': '{{ execution_date }}'}
```

> The params hook in BaseOperator allows you to pass a dictionary of
> parameters and/or objects to your templates. Please take the time to
> understand how the parameter my_param makes it through to the
> template.

You can read more about Jinja templating with params in the [Airflow Documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial.html#templating-with-jinja).

---

It is possible to use `execution_date` in other ways.[SparkKubernetesOperator](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/spark_kubernetes.html#SparkKubernetesOperator) leverages jinja templating with these settings.

```py
template_fields = ['application_file', 'namespace']  
template_ext = ('yaml', 'yml', 'json')
```

SparkKubernetesOperator has two templated fields, `application_file` and `namespace`, meaning you can use jinja templates as values. If you reference a file with those extension, it will render the file and the jinja templates inside.

Let's modify the operator you provided.

```py
submit_compaction_to_spark = SparkKubernetesOperator(
        task_id="submit_compaction_to_spark",
        application_file="/k8s/compaction_s3.yml",
        namespace=kubernetes_namespace,
        kubernetes_conn_id="kubernetes",
        params={
            "k8s_namespace": kubernetes_namespace,
            "warehouse_path": s3_path,
        }
)
```

I'm going to guess what `/k8s/compaction_s3.yml` looks like and add some jinja templates.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: "sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2"
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: "spark-pi-{{ ds }}-{{ task_instance.try_number }}"
  namespace: "{{ params.k8s_namespace }}"
  labels:
    warehouse_path: "{{ params.k8s_namespace }}"
    date: "{{ ds }}"
spec:
  type: Scala
  mode: cluster
  image: "gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v2.4.4"
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  mainClass: org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi
  mainApplicationFile: "local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.4.jar"
  sparkVersion: "2.4.4"
  restartPolicy:
    type: Never
  volumes:
    - name: "test-volume"
      hostPath:
        path: "/tmp"
        type: Directory
  driver:
    cores: 1
    coreLimit: "1200m"
    memory: "512m"
    labels:
      version: 2.4.4
    serviceAccount: spark
    volumeMounts:
      - name: "test-volume"
        mountPath: "/tmp"
  executor:
    cores: 1
    instances: 1
    memory: "512m"
    labels:
      version: 2.4.4
    volumeMounts:
      - name: "test-volume"
        mountPath: "/tmp"
```

You can check the Render Template View for the Task Instance in your DAG.

Please also reference the [example DAG](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/example_dags/example_spark_kubernetes.py) and [sample application_file](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/example_dags/example_spark_kubernetes_spark_pi.yaml) in the Airflow documentation.

Comment: Thank you fo the details I have used as this but I was trying to get execution_date inside dag and get the year,month,day,hour and send that as well into the spark application so how to do that?

Comment: I have tried to use as like this but that is not as expected like execution_date :

execution_dt = new_dag.get_latest_execution_date()
    filter_dt = pendulum.parse(str(start_date if execution_dt is None else execution_dt))
    partition_filter = (
        f"year={filter_dt.year:02},month={filter_dt.month:02},date={filter_dt.day:02},hour={filter_dt.hour - 1:02}"
    )
But here this get latest date if i want to do backfill then latest execution will give wrong date

Answer (score 0):

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66481727/how-to-pass-execution-date-as-parameter-in-sparkkubernetesoperator-operator\\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66481727/how-to-pass-execution-date-as-parameter-in-sparkkubernetesoperator-operator%5C%5C)

```
apiVersion: "sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2"
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:  
    name: "sparkapp-test-{{ ts_nodash\|lower }}-{{ task_instance.try_number }}"
    namespace: "default"

spec:
  type: Python
  pythonVersion: "3"
  ...
  timeToLiveSeconds: 3600 # delete sparkapplication after an hour
```

needed a unique sparkapplication id so I've put `|lower` to lowercase T

```
$ k get pod | grep sparkapp-test
# 1    sparkapp-test-20211122t070418-1-driver                    1/1     Running     0          15s

$ k get pod | grep sparkapp-test
# 2-1 sparkapp-test-20211122t070418-1-a882cc7d46760183-exec-1   1/1     Running     0          4s
# 2-2 sparkapp-test-20211122t070418-1-a882cc7d46760183-exec-2   1/1     Running     0          4s
# 2-3 sparkapp-test-20211122t070418-1-a882cc7d46760183-exec-3   1/1     Running     0          4s
```